# Сортировка массива строк по отсортированному массиву чисел

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка

Задание:
- Создать Массив с именами городов.
- Создать Массив с кол-вом людей в них проживающих.
- Написать функцию, которая принимает два массива на вход, и выводит отсортированную таблицу городов в порядке убывания населения.

Результат ниже в скриншоте, т.е. происходит замена первого символа строки, вместо замены строки.

Голову сломал не могу понять, что не так. Поправьте пожалуйста в коде ошибку, буду признателен за объяснение.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size 9

char cityName[size][size] = {"Moscow","New-York","London","Minsk","Kiev","Warsaw","Berlin","Tokio","Hong-Kong"};
int urbanPopulation[size] = {12330126, 8400000, 8500000, 1836808, 2893000, 1700536, 3950887, 13370198, 7071576};

void sortedArrayCity(int array1[size], char array2[size][size]) {
  char array3[size][size];
  for(int i = 0 ; i < size - 1; i++) { 
    for(int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {  
      if(array1[j] < array1[j+1]) {           
        int L = array1[j];
        array1[j] = array1[j+1] ;
        array1[j+1] = L;
        *array3[j] = *array2[j]; 
        *array2[j] = *array2[j+1];
        *array2[j+1] = *array3[j]; 
      }
    }
  }
}

int main (void) {
  sortedArrayCity(urbanPopulation, cityName); 
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("In %-10s %s %-9d peoples\n",cityName[i],"lives", urbanPopulation[i]);
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Результат]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь манипулировать значениями строк, а не указателями на них. Лучше сделать вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size 9

const char *cityName[size] = {"Moscow","New-York","London","Minsk","Kiev","Warsaw","Berlin","Tokio","Hong-Kong"};
int urbanPopulation[size] = {12330126, 8400000, 8500000, 1836808, 2893000, 1700536, 3950887, 13370198, 7071576};

void sortedArrayCity(int array1[size], const char *array2[size]) {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < size - 1; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
      if(array1[j] < array1[j+1]) {
        int L = array1[j];
        array1[j] = array1[j+1] ;
        array1[j+1] = L;

        const char *s = array2[j];
        array2[j] = array2[j+1];
        array2[j+1] = s;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main (void) {
  sortedArrayCity(urbanPopulation, cityName);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("In %-10s %s %-9d peoples\n",cityName[i],"lives", urbanPopulation[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`cityName` - массив указателей на константные строки. В нём можно менять местами указатели, но сами строки изменять нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Очень уж неприятное представление данных вы выбрали, приходится только копировать строки... Через присваивание такое не сделаешь, вот если бы был массив указателей...

И еще - HongKong пришлось урезать - ну нельзя разместить 9-символьную строку с десятым - нулевым - байтом в массиве из 9 символов.

```
char cityName[size][size] = {"Moscow","New-York","London","Minsk","Kiev","Warsaw","Berlin","Tokio","HongKong"};
int urbanPopulation[size] = {12330126, 8400000, 8500000, 1836808, 2893000, 1700536, 3950887, 13370198, 7071576};

void sortedArrayCity(int array1[size], char array2[size][size])
{
  char array3[size];
  for(int i = 0 ; i < size - 1; i++) { 
    for(int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {  
      if(array1[j] < array1[j+1]) {           
        int L = array1[j];
        array1[j] = array1[j+1] ;
        array1[j+1] = L;
        strcpy(array3,array2[j]);
        strcpy(array2[j],array2[j+1]);
        strcpy(array2[j+1],array3);
      }
    }
  }
}

int main (void) {
  sortedArrayCity(urbanPopulation, cityName); 
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("In %-10s %s %-9d peoples\n",cityName[i],"lives", urbanPopulation[i]);
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего именно иметь отдельно строки (массивы `char *`) и отдельно хранить массив указателей на эти строки (`char **`) и тогда функция swap в сортировке будет иметь следующий вид:

```
int i_tmp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = i_tmp;
char* s_tmp = b[i]; b[i] = b[j]; b[j] = s_tmp;
```

, где a -- массив населения, а b -- массив "строк".

Это позволит довольно быстро поменять местами именно указатели, не копирую все строки целиком